# SQL Server 2005 job failing while rebuilding index on a table with very large amount of data

Tags: sql-server-2005

SQL Server 2005 job is failing while rebuilding indexes on a table with more than 100 million rows. Job failure is not a regular thing sometimes it is successful and sometime it fail.

This is the error which is logged by the job:

> The provided statistics stream is corrupt. [SQLSTATE 42000](Error 9105) The statement has been terminated. [SQLSTATE 01000](Error 3621). The step failed.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Express, Standard, or Enterprise?

Answer (score -1):

You may be deadlocking during the index due to the table size or contention. If you are using Enterprise Edition you can use rebuild with online = ON which may alleviate the problem.

```
ALTER INDEX [ALL] ON [YourTable] REBUILD WITH (ONLINE = ON);
```

Here is a link to further info [Perform SQL Server Index Operations Online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177442.aspx)

Comment: Our database server is idle at the time of index rebuild job so I think this option won't work for me. Thank you for the answer though.